# V & H center img and text on the same line in 3 column table

Tags: image, text, centering

I'm having a trouble about centering img and text on the same line in a 3 column table (later it'll have more rows than 1) .. I have some code but image and text aren't on the same line .. Please help

```html
<table style="border: 0px; width: auto; margin: 0 auto;">
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td style="width: 33%" align="center" valign="middle">
  <p>
   <img width="50" height="50" border="0" style="padding-right:8px;background-color:#fff" src="http://www.luxera-lighting.com/_images/_ikony/35.jpg" alt="Minimálna vzdialenosť od osvetlovaného objektu 0,5m" title="Minimálna vzdialenosť od osvetlovaného objektu 0,5m">
   <h4>Minimálna vzdialenosť od osvetlovaného objektu 0,5m</h4>
  </p>
 </td>
 
 <td style="width: 33%" align="center" valign="middle">
  <p>
   <img width="50" height="50" border="0" style="padding-right:8px;background-color:#fff" src="http://www.luxera-lighting.com/_images/_ikony/36.jpg" alt="IP 20 - Stupeň IP ochrany svietidiel " title="IP 20 - Stupeň IP ochrany svietidiel ">
   <h4>IP 20 - Stupeň IP ochrany svietidiel</h4>
  </p>
 </td>
 
 <td style="width: 33%" align="center" valign="middle">
  <p>
   <img width="50" height="50" border="0" style="padding-right:8px;background-color:#fff" src="http://www.luxera-lighting.com/_images/_ikony/39.jpg" alt="Určené pre montáž na strop" title="Určené pre montáž na strop">
   <h4>Určené pre montáž na strop</h4>
  </p>
 </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

For better imagination I made some preview how it should look like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJIu7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use flexbox to get what you want. Here is a good intro: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

If you want to make it completely dynamic, it'll get more complicated. If you know how many items you have and how often they will wrap, you can set a static width for the `div.imageAndText`

```html
<style>
  .all {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-content: space-around;
  }
  .imageAndText {
display:flex;
flex-grow: 1;
flex-basis: 0;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: left;
align-items: center;
margin: 5px;
  }
  .imageAndText img {
min-width: 50px;
min-height: 50px;
padding-right: 8px;
  }
.imageAndText text {
  height: 50px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
}
</style>
<div class="all">
  <div class="imageAndText">
<img src="http://www.luxera-lighting.com/_images/_ikony/35.jpg" alt="Minimálna vzdialenosť od osvetlovaného objektu 0,5m" title="Minimálna vzdialenosť od osvetlovaného objektu 0,5m">
<text>Minimálna vzdialenosť od osvetlovaného objektu 0,5m</text>
  </div>
  <div class="imageAndText">
<img src="http://www.luxera-lighting.com/_images/_ikony/36.jpg" alt="IP 20 - Stupeň IP ochrany svietidiel " title="IP 20 - Stupeň IP ochrany svietidiel ">
<text>IP 20 - Stupeň IP ochrany svietidiel</text>
  </div>
  <div class="imageAndText">
<img src="http://www.luxera-lighting.com/_images/_ikony/39.jpg" alt="Určené pre montáž na strop" title="Určené pre montáž na strop">
<text>Určené pre montáž na strop</text>
  </div>
  <div class="imageAndText">
<img src="http://www.luxera-lighting.com/_images/_ikony/39.jpg" alt="Určené pre montáž na strop" title="Určené pre montáž na strop">
<text>Určené pre montáž na strop</text>
  </div>
  <div class="imageAndText">
<img src="http://www.luxera-lighting.com/_images/_ikony/36.jpg" alt="IP 20 - Stupeň IP ochrany svietidiel " title="IP 20 - Stupeň IP ochrany svietidiel ">
<text>IP 20 - Stupeň IP ochrany svietidiel</text>
  </div>
  <div class="imageAndText">
<img src="http://www.luxera-lighting.com/_images/_ikony/35.jpg" alt="Minimálna vzdialenosť od osvetlovaného objektu 0,5m" title="Minimálna vzdialenosť od osvetlovaného objektu 0,5m">
<text>Minimálna vzdialenosť od osvetlovaného objektu 0,5m</text>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mr. Rafael, I would like to do something like this: [link]https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJIu7.png

Probably I wrote it badly, sorry